# Implementation of Dijkstra`s Algorithm - Stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: java, dijkstra

Can someone, please, help me with my implementation? I am stuck in an infinite loop, but I don't know why. I think the problem is in the step where I look for the node with the minimum distance... I would really appreciate some help in this.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Dijkstra {
private Map<String, Integer> dist;
private Set<Vertex> unvisited;
//private Set<Vertex> processed;
private Vertex source;
private Graph g;

public Dijkstra(Graph g, Vertex source) {
    this.g = g;
    this.source = source;
    //dist = new int[g.numOfVertices()];
    dist = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for(Vertex v: g.getVertices()) {
        if (v == this.source)
            dist.put(v.getId(), 0);
        else
            dist.put(v.getId(), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    unvisited = new HashSet<Vertex>(); 
    for(int i = 1; i < g.numOfVertices(); i++) {
        unvisited.add(g.getVertices().get(i));
    }       
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getShortestPaths() {
    while (!unvisited.isEmpty()) {
        Vertex current = this.getMinimum();
        System.out.println("Hello1");
        unvisited.remove(current);
        System.out.println("Hello2: "+ current.getId());
        if (dist.get(current.getId()) == Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            break;
        Map<Vertex,Integer > neighbors = new HashMap<Vertex,Integer>();
        for (Edge e : g.getEdges()) {
            if (e.getSource().getId() == current.getId() && unvisited.contains(e.getDestination())) {
                neighbors.put(e.getDestination(), e.getWeight());
            }
        }
        for (Vertex v : neighbors.keySet()) {
            int alt = dist.get(current.getId()) + neighbors.get(v);
            if (alt < dist.get(v.getId())) {
                dist.put(v.getId(), alt);
            }
        }           
    }





    return new ArrayList<Integer> (dist.values());//(ArrayList<Integer>) dist.values();
}

public Vertex getMinimum() {
    int indexOfMinimum = -1;
    //String indexOfMinimum = "";
    int minimum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (String i : dist.keySet() ) {
        if (dist.get(i) < minimum) {
            minimum = dist.get(i);
            System.out.println(minimum);
            indexOfMinimum = Integer.parseInt(i);
        }
    }
    return g.getVertices().get(indexOfMinimum);
}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!!!");
    List<Vertex> v = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    List<Edge> e = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    v.add(new Vertex("0"));
    v.add(new Vertex("1"));
    v.add(new Vertex("2"));
    v.add(new Vertex("3"));
    Graph g = new Graph(v ,e);
    g.addEdge(v.get(0), v.get(3), 1);
    g.addEdge(v.get(0), v.get(2), 4);
    g.addEdge(v.get(3), v.get(2), 2);
    g.addEdge(v.get(3), v.get(1), 6);
    g.addEdge(v.get(2), v.get(1), 3);
    Dijkstra sp = new Dijkstra(g, v.get(0));
    ArrayList<Integer> dist1 = sp.getShortestPaths();

    for (int i: dist1) { 
        System.out.println("Hello");
        System.out.println(dist1.get(i));
    }
    //v.add(new Vertex("5"));
    //v.add(new Vertex("6"));
    //v.add(new Vertex("7"));

}

}


public class Graph {
private final List<Vertex> vertices;
private final List<Edge> edges;

public Graph(List<Vertex> vertices, List<Edge> edges) {
    this.vertices = vertices;
    this.edges = edges;
}

public List<Vertex> getVertices() {
    return vertices;
}

public List<Edge> getEdges() {
    return edges;
}

public void addEdge(Vertex from, Vertex to, int weight) {
    edges.add(new Edge(from, to, weight));
}

public void addVertex(Vertex v) {
    vertices.add(v);
}

public int numOfVertices() {
    return this.vertices.size();
}

public int numOfEdges() {
    return this.edges.size();
}
}

class Vertex {
final private String id;

public Vertex(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}
}

class Edge {
//private final String id;
private final Vertex source;
private final Vertex destination;
private final int weight;

public Edge(Vertex source, Vertex destination, int weight) {
    this.source = source;
    this.destination = destination;
    this.weight = weight;
}

public Vertex getSource() {
    return this.source;
}

public Vertex getDestination() {
    return this.destination;
}

public int getWeight() {
    return this.weight;
}

}
```

Comment: You should provide a code for Vertex class

Comment: sorry abt the incorrect editing. added the code for Vertex and Edge in above code

Answer (score 2):

Your data structures seem a bit confused. In particular you don't seem to have any structure that actually tracks the nodes that need to be considered, in order. `dist` includes the start node, which is always at distance 0, so `dist` cannot be that data structure.

I suggest starting from a pseudo-code version at a reliable source, and being very careful to make your data structures exactly match it in both name and meaning. If you still get into trouble, post a reference to the pseudo-code you are following along with your code. That would make it easier to understand your intent.

Comment: isnt that what the Set  unvisited is for?

Comment: I'm not sure - that is what I meant by "confused". I would have expected to see a PriorityQueue containing only nodes that have not yet had final distances calculated, and that are processed in ascending order of distance.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the problem, but it's suspicious:

```
for(int i = 1; i < g.numOfVertices(); i++) {
    unvisited.add(g.getVertices().get(i));
}
```

Why are you initializing `i = 1`?

Comment: ur right...that is a mistake but im stll stuck in an infinite loop. any other suggestions plz???

Comment: @ueg1990 Okay. It doesn't really matter, since the source node will be removed from `unvisited` during the first iteration in `getShortestPaths`. But whenever your code includes such subtleties, you should add a comment explaining that it's intentional.

Comment: thats where i think im getting stuck at. after removing the source nde, it gets stuck in the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are always setting `current = getMinimum()` while `getMinimum()` does not care if a node was visited or not, so it always selects the `0` node, this is why it loops. Change your code so the `getMinimum()` has to choose different node that the `current` one. You should actually have a heap structure, sorted by the distance, and always poll() the one with the minimum value (and by poll() I mean take, and remove it from the container). Implementing it without the `log(n)` complexity on getMinimum() is not a good idea.